# I've tried to bypass ManyToMany relation between 2 models in Django but not sure that it's correct

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django,but i don't understand the `models.ManyToManyField`.So,to bypass i've tried to create 3 models.A,B and C.A and B are the to models which should be in `models.ManyToManyField` relationship.As i don't understand how it work,i've create a third model called C.And my C model receives 2 Foreign keys coming from A and B,it's the table which puts A and B in a ManyToMany relashionship.I've tried to insert data,and all seems okay.Here is my test code

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.a_name


class B(models.Model):
    b_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.b_name


#The table which links A and B with Many to Many relationship and receive A and B Foreign Keys
class C(models.Model):
    a=models.ForeignKey(A,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b=models.ForeignKey(B,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    c_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.c_name
```

I think that it's specially help when table C model also has attributes.How do you find the idea?Will it create problems in a more complex web app or i can keep on working that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is effectively creating an intermediary using a third model (normally it's done using [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through))

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    b_name = models.ManyToManyField(to='B', through='C')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.a_name
```

What this in essence says is that you're mapping a many to many field to B through the intermediary model C. Django by default creates something like this during a manytomany field mapping:

```
class a_b(models.Model):
    a=models.ForeignKey(A,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b=models.ForeignKey(B,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Implicitly created connecting a to b. But if you want to add additional fields to this connection use `through` to create an intermediary.

So the benefit of doing it implicitly, i.e

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    b_name = models.ManyToManyField(B)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.a_name
```

is that you can use functions like `.add()` and `.remove()` instead of having to create a C object.

A more concrete example, say that I have a person model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

and a ClassRoom model:

```
class ClassRoom(models.Model):
    room_number = models.IntegerField()
    people_in_room = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

Now this lets me add people to a classroom and remove like so

```
c.people_in_room.add(Person.objects.create(name='TestPerson')
```

and remove using `remove` however the relationship of the person to the classroom is unknown, i.e. is it a student or is it a teacher? So what you can do is create an intermediary model

```
class ClassRoomRelationship(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKeyField(ClassRoom)
    person = models.ForeignKeyField(Person)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class ClassRoom(models.Model):
    room_number = models.IntegerField()
    people_in_room = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='ClassRoomRelationship')
```

Now you can explicitly have the relationship of each person to each classroom.